# Tensorboard Callback for all CycleGAN losses

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard, generative-adversarial-network

I implemented the cycleGAN like in this tutorial: https://keras.io/examples/generative/cyclegan/

Now I want to crate a Tensorboard callback for the losses from both generators and both discriminators.

I tried this:

```
# Callbacks
lr_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='G_loss', factor=0.2,
                patience=5, min_lr=0)
log_dir = "logs/fit/" + log_name
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
```

And added it to the `.fit` function:

```
cycle_gan_model.fit(
    data_gen_training, 
    epochs=50,
    callbacks=[plotter, model_checkpoint_callback, lr_callback, tensorboard_callback],
)
```

But I get this error:
`ValueError: Expected scalar shape, saw shape: (1, 30, 30).`
without the callback I don't get any error.
So my question: How can I write the losses per epoch into tensorboard log files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while trying to create a TensorBoard callback for `cycle_gan_model.fit()`. To work around this issue, I had to first run my `train_step` in eager mode using `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` and return the losses as a scalar by applying `tf.reduce_mean` to each of the outputted losses (and optionally, `.numpy()`).

For example,

```py
return {
    "G_loss": tf.reduce_mean(total_loss_G).numpy(),
    "F_loss": tf.reduce_mean(total_loss_F).numpy(),
    "D_X_loss": tf.reduce_mean(disc_X_loss).numpy(),
    "D_Y_loss": tf.reduce_mean(disc_Y_loss).numpy(),
}
```

I'm not sure if applying `reduce_mean` affects the outcome of the training, but I'm able to get TensorBoard working to visualize the losses of the generators and discriminators.